# How do I turn off the ability to change the user account picture?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

In Windows 7 Enterprise, how can I disable the ability for the user to change the user account picture?

**EDIT**

I do not want an empty frame on the Start menu (or on the log-on screen). I want our company logo to display, and I don't want it to be able to be changed.

Comment: Home, Pro, Ultimate??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Win7 Enterprise, I guess they are domain accounts.

I remember seeing a group policy object for this, so I searched and found this:

> If you enable the domain GPO object
>   Computer Settings->Administrative
>   Templates->Control Panel->User
>   Accounts->Apply the default logon
>   picture to all users, the user account
>   picture is set to an empty frame in
>   both the logon screen AND the picture
>   area of the Start Menu.  This is even
>   after replacing the user.bmp file in
>   %programdata%\Microsoft\User Account
>   Pictures with a different bitmap.
>
> If you take a non-domain member system
>   and enable the same local policy and
>   replace user.bmp, the replaced
>   user.bmp file appears as the account
>   picture in the logon screen.  However,
>   once you've logged in, the start menu
>   contains an empty frame account
>   picture.

[Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistadesktopui/thread/51a62a83-7d58-43f1-8219-90e7bbd2e247/)

Comment: I do not want an empty frame on the Start menu.  I want our company logo to display, and I don't want it to be able to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

First open "Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\User Accounts" in gpedit.msc, enable "Apply the default user logon picture to all users", make a 128x128px picture of your company's logo, and save it in "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures" as "user.bmp". And there you go! Your company's logo will now display on the log-on screen and the Start menu!